# Call graph api error using javascript : await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I don't know how to handle it...

I'm trying to make a simple call by referring toI the sample code provided by MS Docs for Graph API, but I get the following error.

How Shell I do...?

**[My Code]
IDE : VScode**

```
const {
    Client
} = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
const {
    TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider
} = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials");
const {
    ClientSecretCredential
} = require("@azure/identity");

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
});

const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
    debugLogging: true,
    authProvider
    // Use the authProvider object to create the class.
});

let user = await client.api('/users/72b2bde1-9b18-4451-8aa0-f61da82426c2')
    .select('displayName')
    .get();

console.log(user);
```

**[Error Code]**

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

If 'await' is subtracted from the 'let user', a 'Promise Pending' error will occur.

```
PS C:\TenantVerse> node .\ConnectGraph.js
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: create a `Promise` and execute the "main" code inside the Promise

Comment: https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/